# Using jquery grid or another grid product with Azure

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, azure

I have an azure cloud application where my data is kept in tablestorage. I've been using home made grids to access the data but I would now like to try out using another product such as jquery grid or the jquery ui grid product.

Has anyone tried using these? How well do they fit with the tablestorage model.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks, Mariko

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can access table storage with jQuery. Because in order to access Azure table storage with jQuery you should do a crossdomain Ajax call, what is not allowed by the same-origin javascript policy. But I could be quite wrong, so if you know the way please share :D

Anyway, just in case it's useful for you, I've managed to read data directly from the Azure storage, using a technique similar to what JSONP does: [Query JSON data from Azure Blob Storage with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489481/query-json-data-from-azure-blob-storage-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid for jquery has a large number of features. Perhaps you can find it useful.
I don't know about azure tablestorage model .

In my application , I use asp.net mvc with JQuery . I have some web services that read from my mvc model layer , transform the data and then return it as JSON .

I use jquery $.ajax to retrieve the JSON data , and then past it to jqGrid

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: Hello, My requirements are only for the azure tablestorage model. Hope someone has experience of trying this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Datajs is a newish oData Library for jQuery, it may be useful, but I'm not sure about it's support for JsonP.

http://datajs.codeplex.com/