# JSON data not returned from Azure blob storage query

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm in the process of trying to create a quiz using JavaScript and JQuery.  I'm storing the data for the quiz(questions, options) in Azure blob storage.

When the json is stored locally adn in the same folder and I use getJSON to make the call, it works.  According to this thread, [Query JSON data from Azure Blob Storage with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489481/), that won't work if the content is in Azure blob storage, but when I tried to make the modifications as described in thread, I get nothing.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Below, I've included my HTML, JSON and JS.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <head>
    <title>HTML5 - Multiple Choose Quiz Sample</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://djmblob.blob.core.windows.net/quizzes/activity.json"></script>
    <!--Adjust for mobile phones-->
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">   
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--comenting out for now...tes<div id="topbar">HTML5 MCQ Quiz</div>-->
    <!--comenting out for now...<div class="spacer"></div>-->
    <div id="navContent">
        <div id="game1"></div>
        <div id="game2"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JSON:

```
dataCallback({"quizlist":[

{
"question":"Josh Hutcherson is known for his main role in the movie series The Hunger Games, but in what other movie was he the main character?",
"option1":"The Polar Express",
"option2":"John Tucker Must Die",
"option3":"The Alamo"
},
{
"question":"Who was the villain in Othello?",
"option1":"Iago",
"option2":"His Wife",
"option3":"Cassio"
},
{
"question":"What was Will Smith’s character Mike Lowery’s middle name in the movie series Bad Boys?",
"option1":"Eugene",
"option2":"Eric",
"option3":"Brian"
},
{
"question":"At the 2001 Academy Award, what movie won both the Best Picture and Best Actor in a Leading Role award?", 
"option1":"Gladiator",
"option2":"Traffic",
"option3":"Erin Brockovich"
},
{
"question":"Who was the original killer in Friday the 13th?",
"option1":"Jason's mother",
"option2":"Freddy",
"option3":"Jason"
},
{
"question":"Who played the main female role in G.I. Jane?",
"option1":"Demi Moore",
"option2":"Megan Fox",
"option3":"Lucy Lu"
},
{
"question":"In what year was Dude, Who Stole My Car? released?",
"option1":"2000",
"option2":"2005",
"option3":"2014"
},
{
"question":"What character does Michael B. Jordan play in the 2015 Fantastic 4?",
"option1":"Human Torch",
"option2":"Mister Fantastic",
"option3":"Thing"
},
{
"question":"Who played the voice of the Lorax?",
"option1":"Danny DeVito",
"option2":"Mel Gibson",
"option3":"George Clooney"
},
{
"question":"What was the character's name Tom Hanks played in the Green Mile?",
"option1":"Paul Edgecomb",
"option2":"John Coffey",
"option3":"Percy Wetmore"
}
    ]       
    })
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var questionNumber=0;
  var questionBank=new Array();
  var stage="#game1";
  var stage2=new Object;
  var questionLock=false;
 var numberOfQuestions;
 var score=0;

function dataCallback(data) {

    for(i=0;i<data.quizlist.length;i++){ 
        questionBank[i]=new Array;
        questionBank[i][0]=data.quizlist[i].question;
        questionBank[i][1]=data.quizlist[i].option1;
        questionBank[i][2]=data.quizlist[i].option2;
        questionBank[i][3]=data.quizlist[i].option3;
    }
     numberOfQuestions=questionBank.length; 


    displayQuestion();
    }//gtjson

 function displayQuestion(){
 var rnd=Math.random()*3;
rnd=Math.ceil(rnd);
 var q1;
 var q2;
 var q3;

if(rnd==1){q1=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][3];}
if(rnd==2){q2=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q3=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][3];}
if(rnd==3){q3=questionBank[questionNumber][1];q1=questionBank[questionNumber][2];q2=questionBank[questionNumber][3];}

$(stage).append('<div class="questionText">'+questionBank[questionNumber][0]+'</div><div id="1" class="option">'+q1+'</div><div id="2" class="option">'+q2+'</div><div id="3" class="option">'+q3+'</div>');

 $('.option').click(function(){
  if(questionLock==false){questionLock=true;    
  //correct answer
  if(this.id==rnd){
   $(stage).append('<div class="feedback1">Correct</div>');
   score++;
   }
  //wrong answer    
  if(this.id!=rnd){
   $(stage).append('<div class="feedback2">Incorrect</div>');
  }
  setTimeout(function(){changeQuestion()},500);
 }})
}//display question

function changeQuestion(){

    questionNumber++;

if(stage=="#game1"){stage2="#game1";stage="#game2";}
    else{stage2="#game2";stage="#game1";}

if(questionNumber<numberOfQuestions){displayQuestion();}else   {displayFinalSlide();}

 $(stage2).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {$(stage2).css('right','-800px');$(stage2).empty();});
 $(stage).animate({"right": "+=800px"},"slow", function() {questionLock=false;});
}//change question

function displayFinalSlide(){

    $(stage).append('<div class="questionText">You have finished the quiz!<br><br>Total questions: '+numberOfQuestions+'<br>Correct answers: '+score+'<br><br><a href="../../index.html">Exit</a></div>');

}//display final slide







});//doc ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution by adjusting my JS as shown below by using the ajax function in jQuery.  The solution located here, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2011/08/10/accessing-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-jquery.aspx led me down the right path.  I hope this helps someone else.

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'https://djmblob.blob.core.windows.net/quizzes/activity.json',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'dataCallback',
                success:    function (data) {

    for(i=0;i<data.quizlist.length;i++){ 
        questionBank[i]=new Array;
        questionBank[i][0]=data.quizlist[i].question;
        questionBank[i][1]=data.quizlist[i].option1;
        questionBank[i][2]=data.quizlist[i].option2;
        questionBank[i][3]=data.quizlist[i].option3;
    }
     numberOfQuestions=questionBank.length; 


    displayQuestion();
    }//gtjson
});
```